Reading delta-table from object_store (GCP, S3..) fails with InvalidTableLocation("Unknown scheme: s3")
Ultimately I like to use the deltalake crate from an objectstore other than the 3 supported (Azure, GCP, S3) but I am already failing to use it for the supported ones.
cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
deltalake = {version = "0.17.1", features = ["azure", "gcs", "s3"]}


soure-code:
use deltalake::{self,DeltaTableError};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(),DeltaTableError> {
    let table_uri = "s3:///DE/customer";
    let delta_table = deltalake::open_table(table_uri).await?;
}


This produces the error:
Error: InvalidTableLocation("Unknown scheme: s3")
When I was debugging I see that deltalake-core::table::builder::resolve_uri_type checks if the prefix is in the list of known schemes produced by factories() that is initialized with "memory://" and "file://", I am wondering how the other prefixes are added.
The build features "s3", etc does not have an impact.
What do I miss to configure?

Please register handlers in the static registry
deltalake::s3::register_handlers(None);
Also please check below link, might be need to update the cargo dependencies.
https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/issues/2610

The error can be resolved by adding the following line:
deltalake::aws::register_handlers(None);

